# PHP: Find all links or link text string and append query string values

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to find all links (or mere link text) in given string (email body) and append custom query string values (google link tracking) in all urls.

I have this as example:

```
$html = <<< S
<html><body><p></p><div align="center"><img
src="https://domain.com/assets/uploads/291c7977c3b2dc87cdfd77533aa95d25.png"></div><br><br>Hello&nbsp;<strong></strong>,&nbsp;<br><br>Type
your message
here...<br><br>https://domain.com/qa/<br><br><br>Thanks</body></html>
S;

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($anchors as $anchor) {

    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');

    $url = parse_url($href);

    $attach = 'stackoverflow=true'; // attach this to all urls

    if (isset($url['query'])) {
        $href .= '&' . $attach;
    } else {
        $href .= '?' . $attach;
    }

    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $href);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

However links are not replaced. In this case, I want to be able to append `stackoverflow=true` to all links in given string but that is not happening.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: FYI: in your example, there is no anchor tag so there is no href's to change

Comment: Yes I don't know how to get this working. I have come up with that so far :(

Comment: this will work on anchor tags, its just that there is no `<a>` element in your example, so most likely this wont change anything. you are looping only `<a>` elements `getElementsByTagName('a')`. duh! :p

Comment: Your code [works fine](https://eval.in/232473).

Comment: @Ja͢ck: Yes but some are links some are links text only like `http://domain.com/foo`. For links text, it is not working since dom only extracts real links marked with '<a>' tag

Comment: Ehh yeah, so what you're after is finding URL's inside text and that's text domain (e.g. regular expressions).

Comment: you can kind of do what you want using regex, but it's really hard to get a regex that matches all URLS because they can be written many ways in HTML eg: `http&#58;//stackexchange&#46;com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out the solution. I first needed to linkify all textual links and then used DOM to do the append work. Here is modified code:

```
$html = <<< S
<html><body><p></p><div align="center"><img
src="https://domain.com/assets/uploads/291c7977c3b2dc87cdfd77533aa95d25.png"></div><br><br>Hello&nbsp;<strong></strong>,&nbsp;<br><br>Type
your message
here...<br><br>https://domain.com/qa/<br><br><br>Thanks</body></html>
S;

// first linkify any non-links
$s = preg_replace(
   "/(?<!a href=\")(?<!src=\")((https?|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i",
   "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",
   $body
);

// now find links and append custom query string values
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($s);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($anchors as $anchor) {

    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');

    $url = parse_url($href);

    $attach = 'stackoverflow=true'; // attach this to all urls

    if (isset($url['query'])) {
        $href .= '&' . $attach;
    } else {
        $href .= '?' . $attach;
    }

    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $href);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

So I only added this portion of code at top:

```
// first linkify any non-links
$s = preg_replace(
   "/(?<!a href=\")(?<!src=\")((https?|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i",
   "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",
   $body
);
```